# USART to serial monitor/pc STM32

Tags: serial-port, usb, stm32, microcontroller, uart

I am having trouble to navigate myself around the synchronous uart on the stm32.
Mainly, how am I going to receive this data? USART supports a clock, tx and rx; but how would one go about connecting this to their pc? I would like to quickly transport my logging data to my pc. This can be a text file of some sorts. I could do this with UART, but it takes ages. I want something faster! This is how i ended at USART.

Is this done via the USB connection? Does the USB carry a clock signal? Are there conversion boards which allow incoming USART and outgoing to USB? I have trouble understanding how this USART could ultimately be interpreted by a pc. Preferably at high speeds, and not native UART speed.

Does anyone have experience on this front and could tell me more?

Comment: There is a misunderstanding about UART. With a STM32H7 MCU running at 140MHz, and APB clock at 140MHz/8, the maximum speed you could config the UART on STM32Cube is 17.5 MHz for asynchronous mode, and 10 MHz for synchronous mode. Read the datasheet of your MCU of choice...

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the connection between a microcontroller and a PC looks the following way:

MCU UART ------ UART-USB Bridge IC ------ USB port of PC

Most of the time, there is no dedicated clock line (which makes it UART), UART recovers clock from the signal itself, USB has its own clock synchronization mechanisms as well.

Some common bridge ICs include CH340 (can be found on fake Arduinos), as well as CP2102 (and the whole family). There are a couple other ones, but I personally integrated these two onto PCBs and they both did their jobs (I found the CPx family reliable, and USB-UART converter dongles cost pennies, but CPx are 3.3V only!). You may have heard of RS232 ICs. As far as I remember, the CPx family supports USART too - there are pins for the clock signal.

Typically, you can increase serial transmission speed to baud rate of 115200 with no issues whatsoever, almost certainly up to 1Mbps (as long as both MCU can handle traffic at that rate and the USB-UART bridge is fast enough).

If your only reason to require USART (with clock line) is the data trasfer speed, then you don't actually *require* USART, UART will almost certainly be more than sufficient (you didn't specify the desired data rate, but I would imagine 115200 should suffice for a text log?)

Examples for boards that use this kind of USB-UART arrangement are Arduino Uno/Nano, STM32 Nucleo boards (which have a dedicated STM32 microncontroller that acts solely as a debugger and USB-UART bridge for the main MCU), and many others.

I suggest you try to ramp up your UART speeds from default 9600 to 115200 (on both MCU and PC side, naturally). The hardware you have should support it out of the box with no issues.

Comment: Hi thanks for your extended comment, while you are totally correct; I would need MORE speed than the 115k. I want to transfer a big portion of data, which is also why synchronous is preferred; since what I have read it is supposed to be a bit more stable.

I would ultimately like to get the highest speed possible, and while you are correct that there are USB-UART bridges on stm32 controllers; I only have an (one) STM32 chip, no other hardware. 

In essence, the thing I am looking for is a U(S)ART to USB converter, which can handle high rates of speed. You happen to know anything?

Comment: Check the ones I mentioned and check their max speeds. They all work at 12Mbps USB, but their actual top speed is at 1Mbps or so. Check out the chip names I dropped for you in the answer. Also, what you want to do sounds like a perfect DMA use case for me. You just tell it what to send and how much to send, and it sends the whole thing. Please, clarify your data speed requirements. Give some kind of specific figure then.